# Should "Ms." be used in a document meant to be translated?

Tags: american-english

The honorific 'Ms.' is very useful in US English, but I can't find any authority on what the equivalent might be in other cultures and languages. Has this reached (say) Indian English? If I use it in something that will be translated to other languages, am I just frustrating the translator because it doesn't cross?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Ms.

If you didn't use any word that might cause some translator some problem, you'd say nothing.

Honorifics are one of the easier cases, since the translator could always choose to keep the honorific of the person's own language, just as some people use *Herr*, *Mademoiselle*, etc. in English.

Edit: I missed this bit:

> Has this reached (say) Indian English?

Of course it has. It's been a long time since it was restricted to the US, and by the time it became the norm for formal and business contexts there, it did so in most forms of English. The Times of India for example would use it as the normal honorific for a woman when talking about politics, business or other "serious" news (historical references or more jocular items such as descriptions of movie plots in reviews might use *Ms*, *Miss* or *Mrs*, but that happens in Britain, the US, Ireland, Canada, Australia, etc. too).

Comment: I would endorse this entirely. The Japanese universal honorific is 'san', which goes after the name, e.g. Yamazaki-san. It doesn't even convey whether the person is male or female, let alone whether they are married, divorced, a feminist or anything else!

Answer (score -1):

Kumari= meaning virgin (read "unmarried") = Kum. (used sparingly in some Indian states)
English equivalent = Miss

Shrimati/ee = Married woman= Smt.
English equivalent = Mrs./Ms.(Now Used Conveniently By Females Who Dont Want to disclose Marital Status)
=>Usage[Shadows the UK English.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/miss_8)

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/miss_8

Comment: Ms is not 'now used' by females to not specify another status. It was invented just for that purpose.

Comment: @Oldcat I meant "now prevalent in use" in India.